# Corda: How to use attachments for reference of previous transaction?

Tags: corda

If I say that a transaction B is valid only when it has some reference to a previous transaction A, can I include the transaction A's state properties/contract code within an attachment in transaction B? How will this attachment be referenced and where will it be retrieved from? Will the participating nodes of transaction B be able to view the contents of transaction A for validation?

Comment: To rephrase, there is a Txn B whose existence is dependent on another Txn A. But both are two different agreements between two different pairs of participants. So I can't have txn A as i/p reference to txn B, since I don't want to consume txn A yet. Thus, to check the validity of txn A within the contract of B, I can either duplicate state A as i/p and o/p within txn B or add it as an attachment. Is it possible to attach that state's attributes or contract code within txn B? If yes, how to convert the state into attachment and reference it in the flow/contract of txn B?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `StateB`, which is only valid in the presence of a reference to a given transaction. You could then define a field in `StateB` of type `SignedTransaction` to hold the reference.

In Kotlin:

```
class StateB(val txRef: SignedTransaction?) : ContractState {
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty> get() = listOf()
    override val contract: TemplateContract get() = TemplateContract()
}
```

In Java:

```
class StateB implements ContractState {
    SignedTransaction txRef;

    StateB(SignedTransaction txRef) {
        this.txRef = txRef;
    }

    public SignedTransaction getTxRef() {
        return txRef;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Contract getContract() {
        return new TemplateContract();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return ImmutableList.of();
    }
}
```

The reference to the `SignedTransaction` is nullable. You could therefore imagine a workflow where you initially create an "invalid" `StateB` - one without a reference to a transaction that makes it valid - and then evolving that `StateB` via a transaction that outputs a `StateB` with the associated `SignedTransaction`, making it a "valid" `StateB`.